# Which fields of service plan provide high level information about services?

Tags: api, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to list service plans usinf the cf api:

```
from cloudfoundry_client.client import CloudFoundryClient
target_endpoint = 'https://api.ng.bluemix.net'

client = CloudFoundryClient(target_endpoint, skip_verification=False)
client.init_with_user_credentials(
   ibm_id,
   ibm_id_password
)

import json
for sp in client.service_plans.list():
    print(sp['entity']['name'],
          sp['entity']['description'])
```

I was hoping to see a list of services with meaningful names and description as are listed in the bluemix web console, however, some of the responses I'm receiving don't really have much meaning, e.g.

```
(("100mb", "Basic"), ...)
```

Which minimal set of fields do I need to extract to list the services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API endpoints are listed in the docs, and the ones of interest to you are [List Service Plan](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/245/service_plans/list_all_service_plans.html)s and [Service Plan Details](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/245/service_plans/retrieve_a_particular_service_plan.html).

You can also get information about everything offered by a Service Broker by hitting its [Catalog endpoint](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/services/api.html#catalog-mgmt).